# How do you access information about the value's run-time type at compile time?

Tags: haskell

How do you access information about the value's run-time type at compile time?

For example, if you want to interrogate the run-time type about specific properties or use dynamic typing.

4th edit: An alternative phrasing of this question can be: ""How do you access information about the value's compile-time type at run-time? For example, if you want to interrogate at run-time about specific properties or use dynamic typing."

For me, these two formulations are equivalent because as I understand in a pure functional language all information about types is known at compile time. This was probably the cause of confusion - I was thinking about "run-time information accessible at compile time" while most people thought about "compile-time information acessible at run-time" :)

Comment: You may want to have a look Hindler-Milney type inference or [type inference in general](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference)

Comment: What about type inference? The haskell compiler produces executable code, haskell interpreter is also a program running in cpu memory. So at some point in time, there is a running program in your computer that has a memory object of the same type of as the compile time type. So if that information is available at runtime, it could also in theory be implemented as a native function and potentially retrieved. Haskell as a formal system is pure in theory, but the runtime is a machine that is executed and is not pure in practice...

Comment: If Haskell were completely pure, you could not use IO or Randomness in any way, so a little bit of impurity is neccessary. Also: memory consists of bytes, which can be interpreted as any type.

Comment: Are you then saying that this information (about the run-time type) is not known at the compile time and therefore it is not possible to construct such a type in Haskell type system? Or this is possible? I don't get your point.

Comment: What you try to do does not make sense. 1. There are no "types" in memory. There are only bytes. 2. It would need a program to check the registers constantly if any register contains the correct bytes. This is WAY more work than storing the information in a new register. Also, how would you do that if your program depends on user input? You would have to predict what the user will enter, which is impossible (at least nowadays).

Comment: I think your question is based on some misconceptions about how Haskell works and therefore is attracting a lot of downvotes (too many IMO). I think there *is* a good question hiding in there, though, which I've tried to answer. Perhaps you could reformulate a bit?

Comment: You answered my question, thanks! I have tried to reformulate into something more PC...

Comment: I gave reformulation another go after it was put on hold.

Comment: It's still very hard to understand what the question is asking. What does the phrase "interrogate the run-time type about specific properties" mean?

Comment: As pointed out in the comment to my answer, the current formulation of the question is even more confusing than the original one. It seems to me like you are switching runtime and compile-time. I don't think you have the right picture about runtime... in a sense, GHC Haskell doesn't really *have* runtime types, other than unboxing/boxing and memory layout information for the garbage collector.

Comment: Well, if Haskell gets compiled into an executable, and that executable runs    on a physical CPU, then Haskell arguably has a run-time :) The other example of a run-time type is when you do :t for a variable in the interpreter. It boils down to how do you define a run-time type. For me, it is the type of the variable at run-time of the program.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I think the whole discussion is interesting (at least for me), so I will ask a separate new question whether Haskell has a run-time type or not :)

Comment: The `:t` case is a little deceptive: GHCi is not just providing a Haskell runtime, but also an interface to the (bytecode) compiler. And it does need to use the compiler to resolve a `:t` command! On the other hand you can probably say that GHCi keeps more of the compiler's type representation than a standalone compiled executable does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Haskell is strongly statically typed, the code to which a value is passed normally knows, without looking at the value, all it needs to know about what type it is.

Therefore at least in the GHC compiler, Haskell is implemented via "type erasure". This means that the runtime representation of a value of a type doesn't normally contain information about its type.  This allows representations to be more efficient and compact.

Also in some cases, especially when using `newtype`s, it allows converting between two types with absolutely no overhead - because the runtime representation of the two types is *exactly* the same, the value can be shared between two pieces of code that treats it as different types.

This doesn't mean that you *cannot* get compile-time information about a value's type at runtime. But you have to ask for it to be included in the runtime information, and the way to do that in (GHC) Haskell is via the typeclass `Typeable` from the [`Data.Typeable` module](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/base-4.7.0.2/Data-Typeable.html).

- This typeclass gives you the name, module name and package name of the datatype constructor as well as any type arguments.
- If you have two values that are not compile-time known to be the same type, but which both have `Typeable` constraints, you can check at runtime whether their types are equal.
- With `cast`, you can also convert values between two such types if they happen to be equal.
- Note however that all the types involved must be *monomorphic*. You cannot 
  use this to compare the types of polymorphic functions/values without first specializing them to a concrete monomorphic type.

There is also the type `Dynamic` (in `Data.Dynamic`) which allows you to encapsulate and pass along values of unknown, but `Typeable` types.

Comment: Your answer is about "get[ting] compile-time information about a value's type at runtime", but the question is about the (rather more baffling) "access[ing] information about the value's run-time type at compile time".

Comment: @ReidBarton It fit the original version of the question better, although that wasn't very clear either. It's what the OP wanted to know, anyhow.

Comment: I am sorry that I caused so much confusion. How about you give me the formulation of the question that makes more sense for you and I will add it  to my question? Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: @GrimMeme "How do you access information about the value's compile-time type at run-time? For example, if you want to interrogate at run-time about specific properties or use dynamic typing."

Answer (score 1):

You are probably mixing concepts of type system and RTTI/reflection. There is no need for Haskell to have something like `typeid()`, `dynamic_cast()` or `is` operator, because you can't pass an argument of a different type than the function expects (well, you can, but it's done via type-level cheating and unsafe).